# Arc land fails: no commits on <feature-branch> which are not already present on target

Tags: git, git-flow, phabricator, arcanist

More or less, I created this scenario on purpose:

```
# We use git-flow.
$ git flow feature start <feature>

# update a file
$ git commit <file> -m '<message>'
$ git rebase -i develop
$ git push -u origin <feature-branch>

# Try arcanist now
$ arc diff

# diff was accepted
$ git flow feature finish <feature>

# feature branch removed, now in develop, let's push
$ git push
```

So now I'm in a state where the branch is gone, and I cannot arc land due to the local branch being unavailable.  **NOTE: git (and gitolite) works just fine**

```
$ arc land

Exception
Branch "<feature-branch>" does not exist in the local working copy.
```

/rant..  I don't see my feature branch in Phabricator's Maniphest.  Why not?

I can pull that branch back:

```
$ git fetch -a
$ git checkout <feature-branch>
```

But I am still unable to land:

```
$ arc land
Landing current branch '<feature-branch>'.
TARGET  Landing onto "<feature-branch>", selected by following tracking branches upstream to the closest remote.
REMOTE  Using remote "origin", selected by following tracking branches upstream to the closest remote.
FETCH  Fetching origin/<feature-branch>...

Usage Exception: There are no commits on "<feature-branch>" which are not already present on the target.
```

And as far as I can tell, I have no recourse for closing that diff.  How do I recover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arc close-revision <Diff-ID>` should close it.  Basically you have two competing Git add-ons that are "landing" your changes. `git flow feature finish <feature>` already "landed" your changes so when you run `arc land`, it isn't able to perform its primary function of "landing" your changes.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm new to phabricator and I purposefully set this up, so I was well aware of the competition.  But I didn't see where phabricator had the option of closing.  It turns out there must also be a background process, because everything seemed to move forward on its own (diff close, updates to show branches, etc.).

Comment: I thought about mentioning the automated processes.  More information on what is happening there can be found here: https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/diffusion_updates/